# How do I create a button with a function, then submit it, with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I am using the following code to add a button to a page

```
$("#myDiv").html("<button id='fileUpload'>Upload</button>");
```

I am then creating an [Ajax Upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) instance on the button.

```
var button = $('#fileUpload'), interval;
new AjaxUpload(button, {
    action: '/upload.ashx',
    name: 'myfile',
    onSubmit: function(file, ext) {
        button.text('Uploading');
        this.disable();

        // Uploding -> Uploading. -> Uploading...
        interval = window.setInterval(function() {
            var text = button.text();
            if (text.length < 13) {
                button.text(text + '.');
            } else {
                button.text('Uploading');
            }
        }, 200);
    },
    onComplete: function(file, response) {
        button.text('Upload');
        window.clearInterval(interval);                
    }
});
```

What I want to do is append the button to the page then simulate clicking it automatically. How would I go about doing this?

**Update**

The code now reads:

```
$("#myDiv").html("<button id='fileUpload'>Upload</button>");
var button = $('#fileUpload'), interval;
new AjaxUpload(button, {
    action: '/upload.ashx',
    name: 'myfile',
    onSubmit: function(file, ext) {
        button.text('Uploading');
        this.disable();

        // Uploding -> Uploading. -> Uploading...
        interval = window.setInterval(function() {
            var text = button.text();
            if (text.length < 13) {
                button.text(text + '.');
            } else {
                button.text('Uploading');
            }
        }, 200);
    },
    onComplete: function(file, response) {
        button.text('Upload');
        window.clearInterval(interval);                
    }
});
$('#fileUpload').click();
```

The .click event does not seem to fire. It is reached in the code but does nothing...

** Update **

```
$('#fileUpload').click();
```

needs to be

```
 $('input').click();
```

Please check the accepted answer for why.

Comment: What's the error you getting? Are you firing this code on start?
If so remember to wait while dom is loaded, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I want to do is append the button
> to the page then simulate clicking it
> automatically. How would I go about
> doing this?

The short answer is that you don't.

The long answer:

First you need to understand how AJAX Upload works.

> Plugin creates invisible file input on
> top of the button you provide, so when
> user clicks on your button the normal
> file selection window is shown. And
> after user selects a file, plugin
> submits form that contains file input
> to an iframe. So it isn’t true ajax
> upload, but brings same user
> experience.

There are two things here:

1. ## fileUpload is not the actual file input
2. Generally, <input type="file"> element cannot be clicked/set programmatically in modern browsers for security reasons.

Comment: I need to fire the .click on the input which is added to the page.

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually have a `click` handler on the button, hence nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Simply by going

```
$('#fileUpload').click();
```

Comment: .click() is not firing. The code is reached but then nothing. I am running $('#fileUpload').click(); directly under   window.clearInterval(interval);                
    }
});

Answer (score 1):

You can call the click handler on the button like this:

```
$('#fileUpload').click();
```

You have already handled adding it to the page.

Comment: .click() is not firing. The code is reached but then nothing. I am running $('#fileUpload').click(); directly under window.clearInterval(interval); } });

Answer (score -1):

```
$('body').append('<a href="somepage.ashx" id="send">Go</a>').find('#send').click();
```